# Sp.Ui.Dialog.js error - Unable to get property 'STS' undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

My problem is that when I start my app for the first time,it shows me an error. The error is: Unable to get property 'STS' undefined or null reference. If I refresh my app then the error disappears.

I'm working with showWaitScreenWithNoClose() from sp.ui.dialog.js. This is my code in my document.ready:

```
loadScreen = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose("Loading","");
```

and yes I've added these scripts to my master-page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/ScriptResx.ashx?    culture=en%2Dus&name=SP%2ERes"></script>
```

So now is my question why do I get that error and how can I solve this? I'm using IE10 maybe that could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this error when calling `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog`.  What worked for me is to wrap my call in an `SP.SOD.Execute` like so:

```
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', modalOptions);
```

for you, it would be something like this (not tested code below):

```
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js','SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose',"loading");
```

References: 
http://blog.solutions2share.net/2013/05/spuimodaldialogshowmodaldialog-do-not.html